# Vue: determine observed object type (distinguish between array and object)

Tags: vue.js

I have simple Vue instance:

```
<html>
  <body>        
    <div id="container">
      <input type="text" id="container" placeholder="enter text" v-model="value">
      <p>{{ value }}</p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.11.10/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#container',
        data: {
          value: '',
          list: []
        },
        created: function() {
          console.log(typeof this.list); // i would like to determine type of underlaying object
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KxVQEw?editors=1111

How to determine the type of the observed proprety in data lets say .list inside 'created' life cycle hook?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`typeof []` will return `"object"`, same as `typeof {}`. If you want to know whether it's for example a JSON object or an array you can use `varname.constructor.name`:

```
console.log(typeof []) // object
console.log([].constructor.name) // Array

console.log(typeof {}) // object
console.log({}.constructor.name) // Object
```

In your case:

```
console.log(this.list.constructor.name) // Array
```

Comment: I was surprised but it seems to work as i desire for observers.

Answer (score 1):

Although there already is a working answer, I decided to use this alternative as it is less code: [`Array.isArray`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_isarray)

```
Array.isArray([]) //true
Array.isArray({}) //false
```